# CSS Transform Scaling with fixed amount

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-animations, keyframe

I have 3 div with different width and height, I want make a highlight with 5px scaling large and small because if ratio 1.1 and 0.9, when the height and width is too big it will be ugly and if too small it is not very visible.

Is that possible to do scaling with only 5px no matter what size of object? or I should just go with 3 different keyframe? or is that keyframe with variable from javascript is possible?

existing code with scale ratio:

```
<div class='cover'>
<div class='col-xs-4'>
  <div id='smallDiv'>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='col-xs-4'>
  <div id='mediumDiv'>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='col-xs-4'>
  <div id='largeDiv'>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bdkrnmko)

Comment: please post some code examples so we can understand your situation.

Comment: If you want to expand by 5px in each direction, that cannot be done by pure CSS alone. That is because you will need to get the computed width and height of the element, and decide on a scaling factor. Also, when your element does not have a 1:1 aspect ratio, that will be scaling with two different factors in the x- and y-axes to get the 5px increase the size, which will visibly stretch/squish your content.

Comment: So you means what I have to create 3 keyframe with scaling x & y to do that?